# J# parametrized thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, j#

I am trying to make a new thread with parameters in J#. I know how to do it in C# using delegates but I doesn't seem to work in J#

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Function));
thread.Start();
```

As you can see I am not using a java thread, it's from a c# library.

As long as function doesn't accept parameters it work. How can I make it work with parameters?

Comment: It's dead, but [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/bb188593.aspx) till 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to pass 1 argument to the function : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx